# How to declare a reference to std algorithm?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am trying to add a reference to std algorithm. How can I edit my code to make it working?

```
double f(const std::vector<double> &arr, bool maxElem)
{
    auto me = maxElem ? std::max_element : std::min_element;
    //...
    x = me(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    //...
}
```

Comment: that code doesn't make sense.. what f()  must do?

Comment: Those are templates, you need to give them template arguments. They return an iterator, not a double, so you need to dereference it (note there'll likely be a bug if you pass an empty array) ([example](https://ideone.com/jA2kKv))

Comment: ooh, so that's what it is.  i'd never wrote such code, it kills possibility of inline optimization

Answer (score 4):

Your functions are *template functions* so you have to specify the template parameter. In this case, using a `std::vector` you need to pass them *iterators*:

Also, to cope with different potential *overloads* of the functions we should *cast* them to the type we require **(thnx to @ChristianHackl)**:

```
double f(const std::vector<double>& arr, bool maxElem)
{
    // deduce the iterator parameter types
    using Iterator = decltype(arr.begin());

    // select the overload type
    using Overload = Iterator(*)(Iterator, Iterator);

    auto me = maxElem
        ? static_cast<Overload>(std::max_element<Iterator>)
        : static_cast<Overload>(std::min_element<Iterator>);

    // need to dereference this because `me` returns an iterator
    return *me(arr.begin(), arr.end());
}
```

Also note I *dereference* the return value from `me()` because it is an iterator (like a pointer).

Of course if your vector is empty that will dereference an invalid location so I recommend putting in a check:

```
double f(const std::vector<double>& arr, bool maxElem)
{
    // Avoid Undefined Behavior
    if(arr.empty())
        throw std::runtime_error("empty vector not allowed");

    // deduce the parameter types
    using Iterator = decltype(arr.begin());

    // select the overload type
    using Overload = Iterator(*)(Iterator, Iterator);

    auto me = maxElem
        ? static_cast<Overload>(std::max_element<Iterator>)
        : static_cast<Overload>(std::min_element<Iterator>);

    // need to dereference this because `me` returns an iterator
    return *me(arr.begin(), arr.end());
}
```

Comment: @KillzoneKid I don't know, can you tell me what error you are getting?

Comment: @KillzoneKid: I think it's a compiler bug. Try this workaround using explicit casts of the ternary operator's operands: `using Iterator = decltype(arr.begin()); auto me = maxElem ? static_cast<Iterator(*)(Iterator, Iterator)>(std::max_element<Iterator>) : static_cast<Iterator(*)(Iterator, Iterator)>(std::min_element<Iterator>);`

Comment: @KillzoneKid apparently, the standard c++ library used by VS includes additional overloads of `std::max_element` (which leads to an ambiguity, [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/g/BeVFkV)). Explicitly static_casting solves the issue, although that's even more verbose than before.

Comment: @Caninonos Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @ChristianHackl Thanks I put your solution in :)

Comment: @Galik: You're welcome. I wonder if VC's additional overloaded here is allowed by the standard or not. See §20.5.5.4 and §20.5.5.5/2.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
if (maxElem)
   return std::max_element(arr.begin(), arr.end());
else
   return std::min_element(arr.begin(), arr.end());
```

You *could* probably obtain a reference to the template specialisation of each "algorithm" you're trying to use, but due to the need to specify template arguments it would be messy and verbose, and thus a false economy. It may also carry a performance penalty (ruining inlineability).

It doesn't really make sense for `f` to behave like this in the first place; try to make your functions do *one* thing well. Arguably, their underlying semantics shouldn't depend on an argument like this.

Comment: well, it is case of exstremum search ,  i can imagine where it can be required with change of semantic (even based on input data)

Comment: @Swift: Sorry, I don't know what "exstremum search" is.

Comment: An alternative (no if-sentences): `return *(maxElem ? std::max_element<std::vector<int>::iterator> : std::min_element<std::vector<int>::iterator>)(arr.begin(), arr.end());`. You be the judge if it's a better way to write it.

Comment: @Clearer: Your name is apt 

Comment: extremum, stray s from typo. it' genralized minimum /maximum search, local or global. E.g. find next peak or "hole" in data stream.

Comment: @Swift: Okay, I didn't know what "extremum search" was either #notamathematician I concede that the semantics aren't wildly dissimilar in this particular example, but the design still makes me nervous.