# What type of std::function to I need to be able to assign it to either std::upper_bound or std::lower_bound

Tags: c++

I have a `std::vector<double> m_x;`

At some point I either need `std::lower_bound(m_x.begin(), m_x.end(), x)` for a `double x`, or `std::upper_bound(m_x.begin(), m_x.end(), x)`

What I want is some sort of

```
std::function<std::vector<double>::const_iterator(std::vector<K>::const_iterator, std::vector<double>::const_iterator, double)> bound;
```

And I can then assign

```
bound = whatever ? std::upper_bound : std::lower_bound;
```

and later call `bound(m_x.begin(), m_x.end(), x)`

Only I can't work out the syntax in the conditional. I'm not sure the type of `bound` is correct either. Any ideas?

Update:

When I adopt the technique in the linked question ([How to declare a reference to std algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49587703/how-to-declare-a-reference-to-std-algorithm)), which is

```
using iterator = decltype(m_x.begin());
using overload = iterator(*)(iterator, iterator, const double&);
auto me = static_cast<overload>(std::upper_bound<iterator, iterator, const K&>);
```

I get the error (msvc)

```
        error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'overload'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a reference to std algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49587703/how-to-declare-a-reference-to-std-algorithm)

Comment: You were close.  You wanted `auto me = static_cast<overload>(std::upper_bound<iterator,double>);`  See https://onlinegdb.com/HysvamWGD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have applied the answer to the duplicate the wrong way.

```
// assuming function template<typename K>
using Iterator = decltype(m_x.begin());
using Overload = Iterator(*)(Iterator, Iterator, const K&);

auto me = bound
    ? static_cast<Overload>(std::upper_bound<Iterator>)
    : static_cast<Overload>(std::lower_bound<Iterator>);


K findValue; // set here
// need to dereference this because `me` returns an iterator
auto value = *me(m_x.begin(), m_x.end(), findValue);
```

Comment: This is very helpful. But really I need to make the assignment to `me` later on, so can't use `auto`. What do I need to do to make it a std::function?

Comment: What's wrong with using `Overload` for the type of `me`? That's what you're casting to! Note, I think, a slight slip in this answer; really you need `std::upper_bound<Iterator, const K&>` although why it compiles the way @Croolman has it is beyond my pay grade.

Comment: Sorry the above comment is aimed at @SasidiranSangamanautram. This is a good answer. Have an upvote!

Comment: I'm not sure this is allowed. You seem to be taking the address of functions from `std` which is UB.